# How to differenciate similar objects in Java without getClass()?

Tags: java, object, design-patterns, identification

I am making a simple game un Java and I think I have a design problem. I have an abstract class Unit that have all units' behaviour (like move(), attack(), getHealth(), ...). Then I extend three classes from Unit: Archer, Lancer, Rider. Each one of those only have a constructor to differenciate them, because they behave exactly the same way but have different stats.

```
public class Archer extends Unit {    
    public Archer(World world, Location location, Player owner) {
        super(new Attack(1, 6, 1), new Defense(1, 4, 2), 10, 4, location, owner);
    }
}

public class Lancer extends Unit {    
    public Lancer(World world, Location location, Player owner){
        super(new Attack(2, 2, 5), new Defense(3,2,3), 15, 5, location, owner);
    }
}

public class Rider extends Unit{    
    public Rider(World world, Location location, Player owner) {
        super(new Attack(3, 2, 4), new Defense(2,4,1), 15, 7, location, owner);
    }
}
```

Now comes the problem. I want to be able to print those units with different sprites, so I make ArcherUI, LancerUI and RiderUI classes that have each sprite. But how do I tell the program to print for example an Archer?

A solution might be do a getClass() for every Unit, but it isn't a good one since I want a good object oriented design.

An other option that came into my mind was to add a name to the unit like that:

```
public class Archer extends Unit {  
    String name = "archer";
    public Archer(World world, Location location, Player owner) {
        super(new Attack(1, 6, 1), new Defense(1, 4, 2), 10, 4, location, owner);
    }
}
```

but then comparing this String would be the same as making a getClass(). What can I do? Is there any idea? or any pattern?

Comment: Clarify "a good object oriented design" please. At first glance on the problem I would use a `String` identifier with a `getName()`. It will make it easier to change in the future `getClass()` is expected to return the class name and nothing else.

Comment: `instanceof`?  Although, I might consider a concept of "renderable", where the `Unit` might know how to render itself.  If you're trying to keep `Unit` clean of UI logic, you could have a `Map` which defined the "renderer" for a given class type and simply perform a lookup through the `Map`

Answer (score 4):

*If there's no real difference between the three classes* (other than the values used to initialize them), I think you should consider replacing them with a `UnitType` enum that would (as a side effect) solve the problem that you're facing.

```
enum UnitType {
    ARCHER(new Attack(1, 6, 1), new Defense(1, 4, 2), 10, 4),
    LANCER(new Attack(...), ...)
    RIDER(...)

    private final Attack attack;
    private final Defense defense;


    UnitType(Attack attack, Defence defence, firstValue, secondValue) {
        this.attack = attack;
        ......
    }
}
```

Then you can make use of your `Unit` class without the need for subclasses:

```
class Unit {
    Unit(UnitType unitType, Location location, Player owner) {
        ....
    }

    public UnitType getType() {
        return unitType;
    }
}
```

This allows you to add unit types without defining new classes and enables you to distinguish between different units in a straightforward manner.

Comment: Additionally, each enum value could hold a reference to the sprite used for rendering an unit of the given type, making the different *UI classes mentioned by the OP redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should take this idea

in Unit Class, you can build new method and properties, like this e.g.

```
Public Class Unit {
    //......Your previous design

    //Solve with something like this
    //the path of sprite
    String spriteFolder = "";

    //Your main constructor, content still Your previous design
    //add new parameter to constructor, "sprite"
    Public Unit(Attack, Defense, 15, 5, location, owner,        sprite          ){
        //......Your previous design
        spriteFolder = sprite;
    }

    //this is the solution
    public getSpriteFolder(){
        return spriteFolder
    }

}
```

And you can call the inheritance

```
//this your inheritance system look like
public class Archer extends Unit {    
    public Archer(World world, Location location, Player owner) {
        super(new Attack(1, 6, 1), new Defense(1, 4, 2), 10, 4, location, owner,   "archer/sprite"         );
    }
}

public class Lancer extends Unit {    
    public Lancer(World world, Location location, Player owner){
        super(new Attack(2, 2, 5), new Defense(3,2,3), 15, 5, location, owner,   "lancer/sprite"         );
    }
}

public class Rider extends Unit{    
    public Rider(World world, Location location, Player owner) {
        super(new Attack(3, 2, 4), new Defense(2,4,1), 15, 7, location, owner,   "rider/sprite"         );
    }
}
```

and you can just call it to draw

```
Archer a = new Archer();
Lancer l = new Lancer();
Rider r = new Rider();

a.getSpriteFolder();
l.getSpriteFolder();
r.getSpriteFolder();
```

or if you instantiate it to array and wanna to draw

```
Unit[] myUnit = new Unit[3];
Unit[0] = new Archer();
Unit[1] = new Lancer();
Unit[2] = new Rider();

for (int i=0; i < Unit.length() ; i++){
    Unit[i].getSpriteFolder();
}
```